# Can someone please explain this Excel function? =OFFSET($A$1,MOD(ROW()-ROW($CL$1),ROWS($A$1:$A$281)),TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($CL$1))/ROWS($A$1:$A$281)),1,1)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset, truncate, modulo

After a Google search, I learned that the following function (or rather, blending of functions) stacks existing columns:
=OFFSET($A$1,MOD(ROW()-ROW($CL$1),ROWS($A$1:$A$281)),TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($CL$1))/ROWS($A$1:$A$281)),1,1)

I'd like to know what each part of that formula does. For starters, I've never seen MOD used like that, and I can't tell if the "-" indicates a minus sign or range. The formula works though so clearly whoever wrote it knew what they were doing.

Comment: Solit it into bits. The first use of - gets a difference between two rows.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whoah. At first I thought this was insanity but this makes sense!

I'll leave the definitions of each function to you to read the documentation, but here's how it's put together:

For the first 281 rows, it's equivalent to the same value in the A row, because it equates to `=OFFSET($A$1, ROW() - 1, 0)` for each row. (OFFSET's fourth and fifth arguments are 1 and 1 by default.)

Then, for the next 281 rows, the second parameter of OFFSET starts over at 0, and the third parameter is `TRUNC((ROW() - 1)/ 281)` i.e. `1`, so now it's equivalent to `=OFFSET($A$1, ROW() - 282, 1)`. So it starts with getting the value of B1 and then goes down.

Then, for the next 281 rows, `=OFFSET($A$1, ROW() - 563, 2`.

Keep extending that formula down enough rows, and it will be a single column containing every value in row A, then every value in row b, then every value in row C, etc.